# Filter syntax in Access 2010 form macro

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I am new to Access programming.

I have a form that I created with Create --> More Forms --> Multiple Items.  The form is based on a query that returns values from three fields, two of which are hidden.  The three fields are FullName, ID, and LastName.  FullName is visible, while ID and LastName are not visible.

I added a text box above the form called txtFilter, and I added a macro to the After Update event of txtFilter, with the intent of filtering out results so that only the FullNames of records whose LastName value is like the value entered in txtFilter.

In the "WHERE=" section of the macro builder, I added the following:

```
='LastName Like '' & [txtFilter] & '*''
```

Note the double ==. When I type a value into txtFilter and press return, I get a dialog box that says "Type mismatch."

How can I fix this syntax so that it does what it is supposed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double quotes and you need to explcitly identify where `txtFilter` can be found; that is, that it is a `Control` on the `Form`. The following is entered in the Where box (without an equals-sign):

```
[LastName] Like [Forms]![frmStaff]![txtFilter] & "*"
```

Replace frmStaff with the name of your form.

Comment: That did it.  +1 for the fast and correct answer.  Do you have any links to good tutorials on this?  A person could spend days on the web looking for a really succinct tutorial that a skilled person such as yourself might know off the top of your head.

Comment: [allenbrowne](http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html) is excellent for Access tips and guides. I don't know of a specific tutorial-site for Access, sorry. **Access Inside Out** is an excellent book - one of the authors tells me it is particularly suited for a beginner, as well as an expert ;)